# yii2 and ckeditor, can't paste content

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

Pasting content from the clipboard to the ckeditor edit field results in a box with the message, that pasting is not possible due to browser restrictions (I'm using Firefox, but it's the same with Chrome). I should paste the clipboards content into the box which works but after clicking ok nothing happens. So I can't paste anything from the clipboard into the editor area.

Inserting a file via the image button works.

What to do to paste content from the clipboard to the editor area?

Answer (score 0):

The problem vanished after copying a new ckeditor version into the appropriate directory under yii's vendor folder.
But I don't know why it works now?